script to change the schedule of a job, it needs to find the schedule associated with the job
using Ola's backup strategy,
there is a job
databaseBackup - system databases full, as you can see on the picture below.
this job is scheduled to run once a week, on a sunday morning.
that is all good, has been running for a while.
Now I need to change it to run every day.
that works fine using ssms, scripting the change and applying it.
however, as I need to get this done in dozens of servers, I will need a script that finds out what is the schedule, and change it and re-apply it to the job
I have not achieved it but I wonder if someone has already done that.


EDIT: Enhanced to include a further check for Schedules associated with multiple Jobs.
SET NOCOUNT ON ;

DECLARE @name sysname ;
DECLARE @freq_type INT ;
DECLARE @schedule_id INT ;

SET @name = 'DatabaseBackup - SYSTEM_DATABASES - FULL' ;

/* 4 = Daily */
SET @freq_type = 4 ;

SELECT @schedule_id = SJS.schedule_id
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules AS SJS
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS SJ
    ON SJ.job_id = SJS.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules AS SS
    ON SS.schedule_id = SJS.schedule_id
WHERE SJ.[name] = @name
    AND SS.freq_type <> @freq_type ;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules AS SJS
                 WHERE SJS.schedule_id = @schedule_id
                 HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT SJS.job_id ) > 1 )
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_schedule 
            @schedule_id = @schedule_id,
            @freq_type = @freq_type ;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Error : did not find a unique Schedule requiring change', 0, 1) ;
    END ;


I have tested it in a few servers and it worked fine, however they are all good standard servers - backups were scheduled and the schedule was for this job only.

Now I will use jenkins to deploy it to the dev servers first, then all servers.

USE msdb;

GO

declare @jname sysname='DatabaseBackup - SYSTEM_DATABASES - FULL'
declare @sname nvarchar(128)

set @sname=(select s.name from sysjobs j
    inner join sysjobschedules js on j.job_id = js.job_id
    inner join sysschedules s on js.schedule_id = s.schedule_id
    where j.name = @jname)

If len(@sname)>0 
begin
  exec dbo.sp_update_schedule
       @name = @sname,
       @freq_type = 4;
end
else 
 print 'There is not a schedule defined for the job'
    
GO

MSDN

that also worked, however, what if it does not find any  schedule for that job?

I modified fthe answer or schedule existance.

you better fix that.  you want to find out if @sname is null first. len does not work well with null. do some research use coalesce or isnull change that answer cheers

select len(COALESCE(@sname,''))
